# typescript can't see declaration file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have `app.ts`

```
import { Name }  from './hello'
```

I have `hello.js`

```
module.exports.Name = "great";
```

I have `typings` folder in which i have `hello` folder in which i have `index.d.ts` and in this file, I have:

```
export const Name: string;
```

I have `tsconfig.json` in which I have

```
"typeRoots" : ["./typings"]
```

What happens is intellisence gives me error in `app.ts` at `./hello` place. it says that it cant find the declaration file. My question is why? let's say it started looking for the declaration in the current directory. It doens't find it. Then it should search for `typings` folder and it will find it there. but why does it give me error?

What I observed is if I run `tsc --traceResolution` , it searches for `hello.ts, hello.d.ts` in current directory, after it doesn't find it, it searches `hello.js` in the current directory and when it finds it, it resolves it. and then it continues to `typings` folder and resolves `index.d.ts` again. but why does intellisence gives me an error ?

Comment: Can `module.exports` and `import (ESM)` be mixed?

Comment: yes. imagine some modules that are written for ES5, we still import them as ES6.